# Access Play Configuration in Plain Scala Module

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-config

I have a Play app that I want to split into:

- rest - Play module that holds the rest interface
- services - plain Scala module that holds actors and external services clients (ex S3)

I want to create a S3Client object class, but when instantiating it I need to read the config values from application.conf. I can not use *play.api.Play.current.configuration* since this is not a play module.

Am I thinking this wrong? What would be the most elegant way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Maybe a better approach would be to factor out all configuration stuff common to all modules to seperate module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use typesafe Config factory

```
   import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

   val conf = ConfigFactory.load("/path/to/your/conf/file/application.conf")

   //init your object with the conf file.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to put a path in it.

If the `application.conf` is in the root directory, the `config factory` will automatically check if it's there.